# Which is the inverse operation to ''Expand'?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am new to Illustrator and can't figure out how to make a single object from many paths and shapes.

I used Image trace to trace a black&white image (settings: abutting, create fills and ignore white option selected). After this, I expanded the object and then I changed black colour to another. Now I want to make the drawing as it was before I expanded it. I tried to use compound and pathfinder but it didn't worked, or maybe I didn't use these functions correctly.

Hope somebody can help me with this.

After image trace :
[image]

After expand:
[image]

After recolour:
[image]

After I used Unite from Pathfinder(the other options from pathfinder don't work too):
[image]

Best regards,

Daniel

Comment: There is no direct inverse equivalent of Expand operations, because the Expand creates shapes with equivalent "rights" and characteristics. Let's say stroke becomes filled shape and you cannot convert it to stroke as it was.... (only cmd+z can help a little bit)

Comment: If there is no direct inverse Expand equivalent operation, then how image trace creates a single object which I can expand into many filled path?

Comment: Can I change the colour of image trace result without using expand ?

Comment: If you provide the picture of interest and ask the specific question you will learn something specific and useful. Now, we have general question which will  add you some general points only

Comment: I will provide an image.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, there's no direct inverse of `Expand` other than `Undo`.

The issue you appear to have is due to the Image Trace feature.

When the image was traced and expanded you then have both back *and* white objects. Using `Pathfinder > Unite` then makes *everything* the same fill color as the topmost object. Which was probably a white object.

WHat you should use rather than Unite, is `Pathfinder > Merge`. This will ensure *different fill colors* remain separate objects.